# Is there a way to make elasticsearch(5.5) autocomplete search by keyword and attribute?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, vue.js, autocomplete, elasticsearch-query

Lets say we have attributes such as `["first name", "phone number", "city", "last name"]`. Is it possible for `elasticsearch` to return back suggestions from each attribute based on 1 keyword. For example searching `"phil"`can give back Phil as a first name, Philadelphia for a city, `philer` as a last name?

I have researched but couldn't find exactly what I am looking for. I am trying to avoid changing the max suggestions from autocomplete to like `100 suggestions` and processing it in either my front end Vue code or backend java code.

Right now I am using the completion suggester and the `elasticsearch` is `sorted based on weight`. As is if the max-suggestions is set to 10 or a specific number, the suggestions are always the same 10 suggestions per keyword. Is there a way to randomize that so that the suggestions can be different? I am also using elastic search 5.5 right now

I would like to write an `elasticsearch query` to search by keyword and attribute and return suggestions for several attributes, not just return the attribute with the highest weights every time.

Answer (score 0):

In your query you can add multiple suggesters, so for each individual field you can request suggestions.

If your mapping looks a bit like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "first_name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "suggest": {
            "type": "completion"
          }
        }
      },
      "city": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "suggest": {
            "type": "completion"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your query could look like this:

```
POST myindex/_search
{
    "suggest": {
        "first_name_suggest" : {
            "prefix" : "phil", 
            "completion" : { 
                "field" : "first_name.suggest" 
            }
        },
        "city_suggest" : {
            "prefix" : "phil", 
            "completion" : { 
                "field" : "city.suggest" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See the documentation for more information about [completion suggesters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-suggesters-completion.html) or [suggesters in general](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-suggesters.html).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I already do this to search by different fields but at the same time because I have weights attached to the separate entity such as first name has a greater weight than last name, then first name will always show up on top of last name. However, my max suggestions is set to 10 so the UI is overwhelmed with search queries and I want the 10 results to be like 2 results from each attribute so 2 last name and 2 first name instead of just 10 first names because the weight is greatest.

Comment: Can you then share some more information about or example of your mapping and data you are indexing?